# How do I retrieve a collection of selected cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a UITableViewController with several cells. Users can enable select feature by tapping on Select button. Once user taps on it, it toggles to Cancel button. What I would like to do is cancels all current selections when user taps Cancel. It should work just like Photo app. I know how to deselect a selected cell but I don't how to retrieve a collection of selected cells, so that I can iterate through it and deselect them. The following is my attempt, but as you can see, it only deselect one cell.

```
func deselectAll()
{
    if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop over `indexPathsForSelectedRows` and deselect each one?

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't see the property. Thanks! Could you reply to the original so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the table view's `indexPathsForSelectedRows` property to get an array of selected `NSIndexPath`s. Loop over this array and deselect each one.